# localhost page is not loading sencha touch framework while using wamp server

Tags: sencha-touch, senchatouch-2.4, mobile-development

I'm developing a mobile app using sencha touch 2.4. I've installed everything correcting using following code.

sencha -sdk /path/to/sencha-touch-2-sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/www/myapp

Now I want to open it in my browser using localhost/myapp/ but it is a blank page...

I want this to be loaded..

![sencha touch[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GugI0.png)]

Answer (score 0):

This is the default sencha touch app... You have to customise/modify it...
The command works fine, you get a dummy app...